# Docker pull access denied for docker-image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image, pull

I am trying to build a docker image for my apache-beam Python script that will be deployed on Google DataFlow. The script compiles a template that is placed in a Google Storage bucket. I am working on a windows machine and running everything on Visual Studio Code.

I have written the following in my docker file

```
FROM python:3.10.9
ADD compile_pipeline_template.py .
ADD first_service_account_key.json .
RUN pip install requests pandas apache-beam apache-beam[gcp]
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="./first_service_account_key.json"
CMD ["python", "./compile_pipeline_template.py"]
```

The structure of my file is simple

```
file/
    | -- compile_pipeline_template.py
    | -- first_service_account_key.json
    | -- Dockerfile
```

I then run `docker build -t docker-image .` upon which it seems to successfully build the image. The image shows up on the Docker Desktop application but does not show up in the file where I built it. I can run it though using `docker run docker-image`.

The problem arises when I run `docker pull docker-image` and it raises `Using default tag: latest Error response from daemon: pull access denied for docker-image, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help me to identify the issue.

Comment: Why are you running `docker pull`? From the steps you've described the image hasn't been pushed anywhere yet

Comment: And the error is not exactly saying that there is a permission error, it may be permissions error OR that the image does not exist. In fact I believe is the latter, as you haven't run `docker push` to upload your image to any registry

Comment: Apologies, I am a terrible beginner. The video, I watched seemed to not do a push; it simply pulled after the build. Maybe the instructor had pushed before video. I will do a push to see if the issue resolves. Can I do a push directly to the Google Cloud Container Registry?

Comment: No worries! Was just wondering why the pull there as it didn't make much sense. Yes you can push to Google's Container Registry although Artifact Registry is the preferred option. You can use this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/pushing-and-pulling) which covers how to authenticate and then push

Comment: Thank you very much. This has been most helpful. I will follow this guide to perform the push.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to log out `docker logout [options]` and then login     `docker login [options]` from the command line to your docker hub account before to pull/push the images.